# INSERT from another table and update the third table

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know how to ask a query to solve the following problem?

INSERT from another table and update the third table

I have table `products`, table `orders` and table `tmp_invoice`

I should make one query that will add all the records from
table `tmp_invoice` in the table `orders` and in doing so to update the table `products` (`products.quantity + tmp_invoice`) for each record in `tmp_invoice`.

Comment: You can't insert into one table and update another table in a single query.

Comment: You need to do this as two separate queries. You can use a transaction to ensure that it's atomic.